# Issue with Dlookup

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have two table, say table 1 and table 2. Columns in two table have below heading.

```
Table 1
1. ABC
2. DEF
3. GHI

Table 2
1. ABC
2. FED
3. IHG
```

As in excel, we use `Vlookup` between column 1 in table 1 and table 2 and than pick value from column 2 of table 2, I need to update value in column 1 in Table 1 using column 2 in Table 2. and column 1 is common in both table. e.g
`Vlookup(Column1. table 1, [1 and 2].table 2, 2 , )`

In access, i m using update query and updating Column 1 of Table 1 using below formula.

```
Column 1.table 1 = Dlookup("[Column 2].[Table 2]", "Table 2" , "[Column 1].Table2  = '[Column 1].table1 '")
```

I am using `Dlookup` for type text. So I have applied formula for string one.

I am not getting desired value that I should get in normal `Vlookup`. Instead, I am getting blank as final result. Why is this happening?

Comment: We are unsure if there are duplicated results in table 2. Dlookup will only return 1 result and im not sure what order it uses to pick that one.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Duplication was none of my concern as I was using dlookup in a mapping table. Reply provided below helped me.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, database notation is `Table.Column` and not `Column.Table`. If your tables and or columns have spaces or other special characters you always need brackets (and you have already made a bad start in your database design, never use spaces or other special characters for names).

Assuming your actual logic is correct what you need is:

```
[Table 1].[Column 1] = DLookup("[Column 2]","[Table 2]","[Column 1]='" & [Table 1].[Column 1] & "'")
```

But I don't think your logic itself is correct unless you are really trying to replace the value you are looking up by.

Comment: Solution provided by you helped me. Thank you. Yes I was trying to replace the value I was looking with new value.